# Reusing a detached thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I have a thread that copy files from source to a new location and I am running this thread from a class and is detached. Thread is running and ending fine but when I re-run the copy (without re-starting the program), with different sources and locations, the thread run as expected but still using the old sources and locations.

I understand that detached threads will automatically release all its resources once completed, but in my case it does not. I have used `std::move(vec)` to pass the values to thread. `v` here seems to be not released after thread completes.

Can someone help me further understand multi-threading.

```
std::vector <FILEEXTRACTPARAMS> vec; //class wide variable
.
.
.
bool CFileExtract::execute()
{
    //initialization/re-initialization of 'vec' here
    .
    .
    std::thread cp_th(&copy_thread, std::move(vec));
    cp_th.detach();
    .
    .
}
.
.
.
void copy_thread(std::vector <FILEEXTRACTPARAMS> &&v)
{   
    for (size_t sz = 0; sz != v.size(); sz++)
    {
        .
        //some tasks done here
        .
    }
}//end of thread
```

Comment: `bool CFileExtract::execute()` you are not passing any params here, so how you reinitialise the vector? Also what returning bool is supposed to confirm?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: How and when do you rerun some thread? I don't see a second run in the code.

Comment: @Olaf, the whole task is run again. Meaning, 'vec' is again repopulated with new values then member function 'bool CFileExtract::execute()' is run again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be a missing [`std::vector::clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) of `vec` between the runs.

Declaring a [rvalue reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing) parameter doesn't magically create a copy, you still have a reference to some object. In this case it is a reference to `vec`.

---

If you want a copy, which is automatically cleaned, pass the parameter by value, e.g.

```
void copy_thread(std::vector<FILEEXTRACTPARAMS> v)
{   
    // use v here
}
```

and then call it like

```
std::thread cp_th(copy_thread, std::move(vec));
cp_th.detach();
```

Comment: Sorry to have bothered you guys! Already found the problem. It was some flag that I failed to reset whenever I assert the contents of 'vec' before re-running the 'copy_thread' Yes, detached thread does release resources after after the thread is completed.

Comment: Yes, detached thread does release resources after after the thread has completed the execution

Comment: yes passing a copy is another way but behavior is the same, simply because of that flag I failed to reset.